# Fill my database as I go with data from an API - Django Prject

Tags: python, django

I would like to fill my database as I go with data from an API that I use that sends me data users.

Here when a user already exists and we just modify his information at the API level, then I would just like to apply the modify the information not duplicate the user, and if he does not exist in my database I will create.
But every time I call the API, if the user already existed in my database, it creates it again (duplicate) and I don't want this side

Note that I retrieve user data in the form of a dictionary

Please where is the problem

views.py

```
from .models import Utilisateur

url='http://userAPI/Users/GetUsers'
y=requests.get(url)
users=y.json()
all_users=users['user']
for one_user in all_users:
   user=Utilisateur(name=one_user['name'],adresse=one_user['adresse'],code=one_user['code'])
   user.save()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Utilisateur(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
  adresse=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
  code=models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a unique field, like *name*, and use it in a `get_or_create` call:

```py
for one_user in all_users:
    user = Utilisateur.objects.get_or_create(name=one_user['name'])
    user.adresse=one_user['adresse']
    user.code=one_user['code']
    user.save()
```

Comment: I can also use update_or_create ?

Comment: @Khalifa I don't think that's an option, but the code block is essentially an update_or_create (just more lines)